# Multi-threading fetch-dequeue C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two threads sharing a lock-free queue. The first thread enqueues stuff into the queue while the second thread waits for an event signal that there is new data in the queue for it to dequeue. Once it dequeues the item the event is reset.

```
//pseudo-code
dequeingThread()
{
 WaitForEventSignal();
 dequeue();
 [..] // do stuff
 ResetEvent();

}
```

Then I thought what if the first thread enqueues more than one item before the second thread finishes with the first one? Then it wouldn't recognize any event calls.

So I then thought about using a variable called `availableEnqueues` and once the signal is triggered the second thread would keep dequeuing`while(availableEnqueues > 0)` and once it's zero reset the event again.

```
//pseudo-code
dequeingThread()
{
 WaitForEventSignal();
 while(availableEnqueues > 0)
 {
     dequeue();
     [..] // do stuff
     availableEnqueues--;
 }
 ResetEvent();

}
```

But this would require a lock and Thread 1 cannot afford to lose even a tiny amount of time on locks and that's why I opted for a lock-free queue.

Then I thought of using two variables one called `totalEnqueues` and another `enqueueIndex`. The first written by the first thread and read by the second, and the second variable read and written by the second thread.

```
//pseudo-code
dequeingThread()
{
 WaitForEventSignal();
 while(totalEnqueues > enqueueIndex)
 {
     dequeue();
     [..] // do stuff
     enqueueIndex++;
 }
 ResetEvent();

}
```

So now since no thread touches each others variables I can avoid the lock. But something seems wrong to me with this solution. I am not even sure if I can skip the locks. Anyone has any better ideas?

Comment: Without a lock there will always be a potential race condition when you call `ResetEvent`. What about using a message queue? You can post your notification message whenever a new job is queued, and the worker thread can use a normal `GetMessage` loop to retrieve them.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go implementing this. Can you direct me a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what your queueing/dequeueing is supposed to be doing, but...

If your 'dequeue' thread is meant to empty all elements whenever they are added (by some other thread that adds a queue item then sets an event), you could do something like:

```
//pseudo-code
dequeingThread()
{
  WaitForEventSignal(); 
  do{
     ResetEvent();
     dequeue();
     [..] // do stuff
  while( queue_not_empty )
}
```

if the other thread adds an entry, then (a) the queue will not be empty or (b) this thread sees the queue as empty, but the event will have been set *after* we reset it.

Also, if we spend some time in "doing stuff" and the queuer adds more than one item then this will take care of that.

Comment: Yes but you didn't address the issue of using the `queue_not_empty` variable without locking it. Did you assume I could use some method provided by the queue or would I manually update it when enqueing or dequeing stuff?

My lock-free queue does provide a `size_approx()` function but I don't really like it's description   `// Returns the approximate number of items currently in the queue.
 // Safe to call from both the producer and consumer threads.`
And the whole approximate thing

Comment: I had assumed whatever lock-free queue you were using would provide you with some size. I see what you mean about "approximate", doesn't exactly instill confidence does it! Alternatively, what happens when you pull an item from the queue when it is empty ? do you get NULL or something which tells you the same thing ?

Comment: `// Removes the front element from the queue, if any, without returning it.
// Returns true on success, or false if the queue appeared empty at the time pop was called.`


Do you think its safe to rely on that? Seems good to me

Comment: Er, that sounds like it just removes an element "without returning it"... which would be bad if there was one?

Comment: No worries I found `try_dequeue` which does the job :
`Attempts to dequeue an element; if the queue is empty, returns false instead. If the queue has at least one element, moves front to result using operator=, then returns true.`

Comment: Excellent! - that should do the job. With the sequence I gave, the "worst" that can happen is that the other thread adds an item... then this thread gets control, removes the item, goes around again, resets the event, gets false this time and goes back to waiting ... the other thread continues and sets the event - you get the event but try_dequeue gives false - because you have already processed it. i.e. don't assume you will always get a queue item on every event.